# Can I post SO questions and answers in a personal blog?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, legal

Can I post or otherwise use SO questions and answers answers in a personal blog?

Comment: Considering there's a `share` button and a badge for sharing a link to a post that was visited  by x unique IPs, I think yes...

Comment: @Unihedron I believe me_digvijay is asking about copying the text rather than just linking to it.

Comment: Also see [What is up with the source code license on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/what-is-up-with-the-source-code-license-on-stack-overflow/25957#25957).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Yes, as all content posted to Stack Overflow (or indeed any Stack Exchange site) is under the [cc-by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licence.

For other people's questions and answers, you can use them as long as you [preserve the attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) (who wrote it and when) and include a link back to the original question/answer on Stack Overflow.

As for your own questions and answers, you own the content so you can do with it what you will on other sites. It would be best to include an "attribution" link back to the question/answer on Stack Overflow, however this is not an absolute requirement in this case.

Comment: Do you still own the content after other users have made edits? Or is attribution mandatory in that case?

Comment: @Stijn, as I understand the original content is your own, others can build on it per cc-by-sa and the result is a derivative work of the original. Now fetch me five lawyers and we can discuss *derivative work*.

Comment: "*It would be best to include an "attribution" link back to the question/answer on Stack Overflow.*" "Best" as in nicest and most welcomed, or "best" as in best legal interest? It sounds pretty vague.

Comment: @luk32 - nicest and most welcomed. This is the OP's own content, they can do with it what they want.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Aye, we all want to know, precise to the bit, at which point enough others did enough work to create a derivative work with its own copyright protection... ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator I'd say it becomes a derivative work as soon as another user contributes to it. (The new revision is, anyhow - the original revision is still the author's.)

Comment: @Michelle: Actually, it does not. Whether a new revision is a new though derived work itself, that's where you need to consult a lawyer; it depends on the original work, and how much it was changed (as well as who has the better lawyer, and in which court you ask).

Comment: @Deduplicator Okay, I'd say to be safe, assuming you're not actively looking to avoid linking back and attributing for revisions that have been edited, someone who doesn't have money to blow on a lawyer could err on the side of caution and assume any revision that has been edited by another user is a derivative work and act accordingly. Happy? :P

Comment: Why wouldn't you give an attribution link back to the question?

Comment: @MikeD. For your own content you don't *have* to, but I agree it would daft not to - after all there's badges for publicising questions elsewhere.

Comment: Its also worth mentioning (as per the terms of the cc-by-sa license) that any modifications you make have to be released under the same license. This is the "sa" part of the license. Also you are supposed to include a link to the licence so that your website visitors know the terms for their own use of the material.

Answer (score 18):

> Can I post/use my/others SO questions/answers in my personal blogs?

Yes, you can. The copyright is still yours, you are just licensing the content to Stack Exchange.

If you post answers/questions by *other* users, you must [link back to the post and include details of the OP](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: would it be mandatory to attribute or is it just a `suggestion`?

Comment: @user13107 - part of our licensing (see the footer), includes the attribution requirement. That means, that for content that you did not produce yourself, yes, it is mandatory. Why wouldn't you want to give back attribution to the people who created the original content?

Comment: @Oded the same way SO adds nofollow to linked and quoted sources, maybe?

Comment: @Matsemann - you seem to conflate nofollow with attribution.

Comment: I’ve changed “should” to “must” in the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: @user13107 you should always attribute others work even if the license allows you to use without attribution

Answer (score 0):

If they are solely your then you can post them anywhere but if the content is posted by other users you should take a look at below points.

- In the event that You post or otherwise use Subscriber Content
  outside of the Network or Services, with the exception of content
  entirely created by You, You agree that You will follow the
  attribution rules of the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike
  license as follows:
- You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually
  displays or otherwise indicates the source of the Subscriber Content
  as coming from the Stack Exchange Network. This requirement is
  satisfied with a discreet text blurb, or some other unobtrusive but
  clear visual indication.
- You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content
  includes a hyperlink directly to the original question on the source
  site on the Network (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
- You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually
  display or otherwise clearly indicate the author names for every
  question and answer so used. You will ensure that any such Internet
  use of Subscriber Content Hyperlink each author name directly back to
  his or her user profile page on the source site on the Network (e.g.,
  https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username), directly to the Stack
  Exchange domain, in standard HTML (i.e. not through a Tinyurl or
  other such indirect hyperlink, form of obfuscation or redirection),
  without any “nofollow” command or any other such means of avoiding
  detection by search engines, and visible even with JavaScript
  disabled.

For more clarification feel free to visit the https://stackexchange.com/legal page